# Scaling SVG in HTML5 or In svg file

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to scale SVG with style attribute from html or css file

**Example:**
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_path2

If I change SVG element width or height it does not scale

```
<svg height="200" width="350">
```

An SVG with `<img src="test.svg" width="350">` tag width attribute is also not working

Answer (score 0):

The SVG is based on constant point, so i won't scale. If you have to scale something like the attached example you can use

```
transform: scale(1.2);
```

however it isn't recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add a viewBox tag if you want SVG to change as the width/height changes e.g.

```html
<svg height="400" width="450" viewBox="0 0 400 450">
<path id="lineAB" d="M 100 350 l 150 -300" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

so now when I change the width and height (and nothing else) the SVG scales.

```html
<svg height="200" width="225" viewBox="0 0 400 450">
<path id="lineAB" d="M 100 350 l 150 -300" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

The SVG they made is not responsive SVG. You can try with any other SVGs. So sorry for it. If you want to be clear just resize the browser window and check whether it is responsive or not. They are not.

Thanks for the downvote learned something and want to mention something "When exporting SVGs with Adobe Illustrator you need to explicitly mention that the SVG should be responsive. So, with the idea of transform scale CSS, you are stuck with a screen size and it won't be responsive like mentioning it in illustrator. So there is a difference between both. If still wrong some people could help me. If this is correct upvote me.